# generating cross product for list of lists

Tags: python, permutation

I have a python list like `[[1 2 3] [4 5] [3] [1]]` and I want to generate all possible permutations. The output should be something like

`[[1 4 3 1] [1 5 3 1] [2 4 3 1] [2 5 3 1] [3 4 3 1] [3 5 3 1]]`

I thought about loops but the number of nested loops would vary according to the input. Can someone suggest a good algorithm?

Comment: Aren't these the combinations?

Comment: Can you please provide your examples and expected output in valid python.

Comment: @metatoaster This appears to be a different kind of problem to that question.

Comment: Also, what makes each sublist to be of length 4? It implies you are not allowing duplicate integers..

Comment: @ebarr no code was shown, output appears to be a set of all number of integers, and max length of 4.  It's a completely unclear question and questioner needs to put some code to distinct it from the possible duplicate.  At least show code using it and show where it doesn't work.

Comment: The OP wants all combinations where only one value is selected from each sublist at a time, hence 4 values and the last two always being the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is a [carthesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product). `itertools` [has a function `product`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) that does exactly that:

```
import itertools
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [3], [1]]
p = itertools.product(*a)
print list(p)
```

This outputs

```
[(1, 4, 3, 1),
 (1, 5, 3, 1),
 (2, 4, 3, 1),
 (2, 5, 3, 1),
 (3, 4, 3, 1),
 (3, 5, 3, 1)]
```

Comment: I was just about positng the same

Comment: I was just writing some absolute rubbish to try and do the same.